# i would like to stop ajax request after 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My ajax function works every 15 seconds. I would like to stop it after 2 minutes.

How can i do this?

```
 window.setInterval(function () {
      var request = $.ajax({
         ...
      })
 }, 15000);
```

Comment: erm... what happened to the rest of the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `clearInterval`, the `clearInterval()` method clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method.

```js
var request;
var _timer = setInterval(function() {

  request = $.ajax({
    ...
  });

}, 15 * 1000);

setTimeout(function() {

    clearInterval(_timer);
    request.abort(); // If you want to abort the xhr which are still executing after 2 minutes

}, 2 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Another option is just to do it after seven iterations in the main timer.

Comment: @nicael yes you can do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var t=0;
var i=15000;
var m=Math.abs( 2 * 60 * 1000 );

var tmr=window.setInterval( function () {
     var request = $.ajax({ /* do something */ });
     t+=i;
     if( t >= m ) clearInterval( tmr );
}, i );
```

Noted @Jay!

Virtually the same as the answer posted by @void - apart from not killing an active ajax request. To cancel the interval it must be assigned as a variable which can be referenced when calling the `clearInterval` method.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.